# Weblogic commons-codec Base64 nosuchMethodError on SUNOS

Tags: java, spring-mvc, weblogic, weblogic12c

Code used for decoding:
Base64.decodeBase64("String");

Commons-codec jar version: 1.9

Exception:
nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(Ljava/lang/String;)

Environment Details:
OS: SunOS
Version: 5.11
Java Version: 1.8.0_221 (Oracle corporation)

Same WAR working in below environment
Environment Details:
OS: AIX
Version: 7.1
Java Version: 1.8.0_191 (IBM JDK)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting a `NoSuchMethodError`, that means that you have a runtime version incompatibility problem.  Some part of the codebase depends on<sup>1</sup> a version of `Base64` that has a method called `decodeBase64` that takes a single `String` argument.  But the version of the class that has been loaded doesn't have that method.

There is a clue in the javadoc for the method.  It says that the method was added to the `Base64` in version 1.4 of the API.  So check the JAR files that are deployed to see if there is an older (pre 1.4) version of the Apache Commons Codec JAR on the runtime classpath.

---

<sup>1 - It could be a static dependency; i.e. a normal method call.  It could also be a dynamic dependency; e.g. attempting to lookup the method using reflection.</sup>

Comment: I Checked that version also. 1.9 only there. same WAR working fine in AIX but not working in SunOS. Is there any configuration need to do?

Comment: Check that you are using the same version of Weblogic on both platforms.

Comment: weblogic version is same. Only difference is environment

Comment: It is possible that you have two different Apache Commons Codec JAR files in your WAR file.  Check.  If that doesn't help, change the JVM config to include "-verbose:class" and see where the `Base64` class is being loaded from.

Comment: Only you can find the problem, because only you have access to the environment. My guess is that there is a second `Base64` class in one of the jar, diverent environments can order jars in the classpath differently and java will load the class from the first jar it finds. suggestion by @StephenC is the best, use `-verbose:class` to find which jar `Base64` is loaded from. Is it the one you expect?